# AutomationAnywhere file size vs effciency

Tags: performance, rpa, max-size, automationanywhere

I'm wondering if size of AAE file has an impact on efficiency, speed of BOT. I mean when I wrote first version of my BOT it had like 6.7 MB but after adding some additional error handling and additional if statements. it grew up to 11.5 MB. It did not change the speed of  BOT but I'm wondering what is the maximal BOT size which wont affect it's speed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of the **atmx** files will not have an impact on the speed at which your BOT would run. You could have a file that is as big as you want it to be, although that is not the best practice, and still have your bot work fine.

However, its always a good practice to Break down a chunk of task to small sub tasks and run those tasks via `Run Task` command in the command library.

Having said that, what might impact the performance is the logic that goes behind it. For example a bot that is stuck in a loop can take up system resources which would eventually crash the Device when all its resources has been consumed by the endless loop.

**P.S: Snap shot of the `.atmx` file that is about 4x times bigger and works just fine in terms of performance** 
[image]